# NSUserDeafults not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, session, nsuserdefaults

I'm trying to get value from my database and keep it in NSUserDefault to create a session between pages.

Here is my code:

```
NSString *userStatus = [[[dataDict valueForKey:@"user"]objectAtIndex:0]valueForKey:@"status"];
NSUserDefaults *userStatusID=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[userStatusID setObject:userStatus forKey:@"status"];
[userStatusID synchronize];
```

Here is the dataDict:

```
user =({
        "event_id" = 9;
        "job_title" = Manager;
        "last_login" = "2014-08-06 13:40:53";
        name = "********";
        id = ******;
        phone = ************;
        photo = "**********.jpeg";
        "status" = 1;
        }
```

Here is the codes to grab it:

```
NSUserDefaults *userStatusID=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *statusID = [userStatusID objectForKey:@"status"];
NSLog(@"Created status: %@",statusID);
```

The status only can be either 1 or 0 but the log always said that the status is null. I tried to create NSUserDefault for another field such as name and id and it works well. Do you know where is i do wrong? Thank you for your help

SOLVED:
Sorry for my silly mistake. Actually my code worked very well but i did mistake by put the code in login form while the dictionary created after login which is in home form. It worked well after i moved the code. Thanks for everybody help anyway, i just figured it out after trying all of your code ^^ Love you bud

Comment: Did you check userStatus Value. try to print it using NSLog and check

Comment: NSString *userStatus = [[[dataDict valueForKey:@"user"]objectAtIndex:0]valueForKey:@"status"]; -- in here what the result u get

Comment: Is `status` a string in that dictionary, or a number?

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing this:

```
NSString *userStatus = [[[dataDict valueForKey:@"user"]objectAtIndex:0]valueForKey:@"status"];
```

with this:

```
NSString *userStatus = [[[dataDict valueForKey:@"user"]objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"status"];
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
NSString *userStatus = [[[dataDict valueForKey:@"user"]objectAtIndex:0]valueForKey:@"status"];
```

with:

```
NSString *userStatus = dataDict[@"user"][0][@"status"];
```

And you can `NSLog(@"userStatus:%@", userStatus)` before save it to check value is correct.